# need help converting range of numbers (ex:0-7) to an average (ex: 3.5) in R

Tags: r

This is the data I am using in R:

```
library(Sleuth2)
ex22.20
```

I am trying to convert the column "Years" from a range of numbers (0-7) to the mean between the two numbers (3.5)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution where the means are computed on the levels of `ex22.20$Years` before being applied.

```
library(Sleuth2)
head(ex22.20)
#   Exposure Years Deaths Risk
# 1        0   0-7     10  262
# 2        0  8-11     12  243
# 3        0 12-15     19  240
# 4        0 16-19     31  237
# 5        0 20-23     35  233
# 6        0 24-27     48  227

levels(ex22.20$Years)
# [1] "0-7"   "8-11"  "12-15" "16-19" "20-23" "24-27" "28-31"

mid.values <- sapply(strsplit(levels(ex22.20$Years), "-"),
                     function(x)mean(as.numeric(x)))
mid.values
# [1]  3.5  9.5 13.5 17.5 21.5 25.5 29.5

ex22.20$Years <- mid.values[ex22.20$Years]

head(ex22.20)
#   Exposure Years Deaths Risk
# 1        0   3.5     10  262
# 2        0   9.5     12  243
# 3        0  13.5     19  240
# 4        0  17.5     31  237
# 5        0  21.5     35  233
# 6        0  25.5     48  227
```

Comment: @BenSameshima, I'm glad it helped. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, would you please mark it as accepted? You can follow the instructions at stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner to get the mean of a specific row from the data (the first one, in this case, 0-7):

```
mean(range(lapply(strsplit(levels(ex22.20$Years)[1],"-"),as.numeric)))
```

Which returns

```
[1] 3.5
```

Explanation:

1. use `levels` to extract the desired data string `"0-7"`
2. use `strsplit` to turn it into a list of numeric strings `[["0" "7"]]`
3. use `lapply` to apply `as.numeric` and turn it into a list of numbers `[[0 7]]`
4. use `range` to generate a range with those numbers as endpoints
5. use `mean` to calculate the mean.